# How to return data from two tables in one resource with Web API, MVC5 via Repository

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern, asp.net-web-api

I am working with Web API 2, MVC 5 and the resource I need to return should be a combination of two similar tables, with a type that differentiates them (ie Teacher Assignment, Student Assignment).  The resource will need CRUD operations.  Currently, the request comes in to the controller, which goes to a Repository which has a Linq query to pull the data from the db:

```
public IQueryable<StudentAssignment> GetStudentAssignments(int activityID ) {
  return ActivityDBContext.StudentAssignements.Where(x => x.OrgID == this.MultiTenantID && x.ActivityID == activityID).OrderBy(x => x.StudentAssignementID).AsQueryable();
  }

public IQueryable<TeacherAssignments> GetTeacherAssignments(int activityID) {
  return ActivityDBContext.TeacherAssignments.Where(x => x.OrgID == this.MultiTenantID && x.ActivityID == activityID && x.IsActive).OrderBy(x => x.StaffAssignmentID).AsQueryable();
  }
```

And in the controller:

```
[HttpGet, Route("activities/{id:int}/assignments")]
public List<AssignmentExternalList> List(int id, int page = 1, int pageSize = 50) {
List<AssignmentExternalList> assignments = new List<AssignmentExternalList>()
   {
   Repository.GetStudentAssignments(id).ToExternal(page, pageSize),
   Repository.GetTeacherAssignments(id).ToExternal(page, pageSize)
   };
return assignments;
}
```

My question is, should I be doing this differently?  I am a newbie.  Would it be better to do a join in one linq query instead of two separate queries for each Create, Update, Delete method.  Some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return them in one collection (which it looks like you might want to from the paging parameters), you'll need to create a class that holds the common properties of the student and teacher assignments and have them inherit from that. Then have your controller return a collection of that parent type.

```
[HttpGet, Route("activities/{id:int}/assignments")]
public List<Assignment> List(int id, int page = 1, int pageSize = 50) {
     List<Assignment> assignments = new List<Assignment>();
     assignments.AddRange(Repository.GetStudentAssignments(id).ToExternal(page, pageSize));
     assignments.AddRange(Repository.GetTeacherAssignments(id).ToExternal(page, pageSize));

     return assignments;
}
```

Comment: OK, that is what I'm doing.  +1 for AddRange, thanks.  So, this is an OK way to do this?

Comment: It's how I would do it. Whatever makes the most sense to you and others who will be reading your code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you could just create one method to retrieve your data and use Linq [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)

Comment: OK, hadn't seen the obvious, thanks.  Any chance of an example based on above code?  Struggling to get it to work.